# What are these "fence-posts" with Kanji on them in Samurai Champloo?

Tags: culture, japan, samurai-champloo

During episode 2 of Samurai Champloo, Mugen's walking through some wooden posts with kanji on them. What are they? I can't imagine they're grave-stones or something, since they're all bunched in a row like a fence. If it matters, the anime is set in the Edo period-ish, roughly in the 1840s.
[image: mugen walking through fenceposts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [卒塔婆（sotoba）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%BF%E5%A1%94%E5%A9%86) and seen commonly in Japanese cemeteries. They are normally placed at the back of grave stones like the following ([source](https://ishiyachidori.com/%E5%8D%92%E5%A1%94%E5%A9%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E4%BD%95%EF%BC%9F/)):

[image]

Usually some matra or names of people buried there are written on them.

Apparently the ones similar to the picture you posted can be found in [a Japanese temple](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E5%89%9B%E8%AD%89%E5%AF%BA), but most probably it's unique to this temple (or at least it's rare; I've never seen things like this).

[source](https://itamiwake.com/2014/08/kongoushouji.html) (also mentioned in the Wikipedia article above):

[image]